# Trying to recreate a graph using Tikzpicture and Pgfplots, doesn't turn out the way I want it to

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

Trying to recreate this graph:
[image]

however mine turns out like this:

[image]

Issues that I am having:

1. The curve doesn't look very smooth and even.
2. Nothing I try to draw (\draw) appears in the figure, I'm trying to add the text inside the figure.

Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel = {lowest to highest},
                ylabel = {income earned},
                xmin = 0,
                xmax = 1,
                ymin = 0,
                ymax = 1
    ]
        \addplot[smooth]{x};
        \addplot[smooth, thick, label=$x$]{x^2};
        \coordinate (P) at (0,0);
        \node[rotate=45] (N) at (P) {lorenz curve};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The last part trying to draw the text node was just something I found here: [TikZ diagonal text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66547/tikz-diagonal-text). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel = {lowest to highest},
                ylabel = {income earned},
                xmin = 0,
                xmax = 1,
                ymin = 0,
                ymax = 1
    ]
        \addplot[domain=0:1]{x} node[midway,above,sloped]{Line of equality}
        node[midway,below,sloped]{Concentration area};
        \addplot[domain=0:1,smooth, thick, label=$x$]{x^2}
        node[midway,below,sloped]{Lorenz curve};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Only thing is that the "concentration area" comes out at an awkward position for me, the  y=x line goes through it, unlike your picture above. How would I move it?

Comment: Use [below=1ex] or so to adjust the positioning.

Comment: @Chisq Does that happen when you compile the above or when you embed it into another document (in which you e.g. did not say `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}`)?

Comment: I'm writing every chapter in a separate .tex file, that i \input into main.tex. However, typing  `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` in the chapter.tex instead didn't help. `[below=1ex]` moved it somewhere else instead.

Comment: @Chisq It is hard for me to debug this because the above does not have the issue, nor do I know what I can do to reproduce it. There are many conceivable reasons. How about `\addplot[domain=0:1]{x} node[midway,above,sloped]{Line of equality};
  \node[rotate=40] at (0.5,0.4 ){Concentration area};`?

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you, adding the node separate from the line worked. Any idea why rotating it at 45 degrees doesnt make it parallell to the $x=y$?

Comment: @Chisq This is because `pgfplots` rescales both directions independently to produce a plot that has the preset `width` and `height`. You can turn this off by adding `axis equal image` to the options of the axis, in which case the `x` and `y` units will be the same (in this example).